# Extracting data from two tables with same in the form of appending

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Following is my table with data :

Table Name : jay

```
RollNo  Name    Age

58      Jay     18
```

Table Name : ren

```
RollNo  Name    Age

23      Renish  20
```

How can I extract data in following form :

```
RollNo  Name    Age

58      Jay     18

23      Renish  20
```

Please Help me.

Comment: It looks like just a simple `UNION`. What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing.
I have tried some normal queries.

Comment: How is it possible? @Barmar

Comment: @Jay There are 4 identical answers that answer that question. Why are you asking me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.
```

---

```
select * from jay
UNION 
select * from Ren
```

## [SQl FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f37b5/2)

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it is SQL use below query

```
SELECT RollNo, Name, Age FROM jay
UNION
SELECT RollNo, Name, Age FROM ren
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SQL UNION` clause/operator is used to combine the results of two or more SELECT statements. To use `UNION`, each `SELECT` must have:

1. Same number of columns selected
2. Same number of column expressions
3. Same data type
4. Have them in the same order, but they do not have to be the same length.

Try this:

```
select * from jay
UNION ALL
select * from Ren
```

Read more about `UNION` operator [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unions-clause.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Union All` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jay
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ren
```

### [Take a look of this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)